# Hide main page content block

Tags: blocks

I've configured the **Main page content** block to show on all pages except those listed. The paths I have listed are:

- commodity-selection
- commodity-selection/*
- value-chain-studies
- value-chain-studies/*

When visiting [one those pages](http://eiado.prevision.com.au/commodity-selection/selection-matrix) however, the main page content is still present. Even after all caches are cleared.

Is there a trick to hiding the Main page content block?

What I'm trying to achieve is a page that that presents its content within a tab. Other tabs are populated with content from other nodes.

My approach so far has been to use Quicktabs to create a block with the node content  I want (ie. node 1, 3, 5). I place that block in the content region and configure it to show on the page I want (node 1). I planned to then hide the Main page content block to hide the node 1 content, without success.

Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main content is required. To hide it you can do this (I'm using bartik and hiding only for article) in theme's template.php:

```
function bartik_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if($node = menu_get_object()){
    if ($node->type == 'article') {
      $vars['page']['content']['system_main']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

However, I think you need to rethink your approach and either use Views, [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds), or [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) to take over the rendering.